# UITableViewCell subClass Xib subviews change its frame automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

I am facing a very strange problem, hope its a bug in Xcode 6.
When i open My Xib file of UITableViewCell subclass, Some subviews changes its position means Y position , width , height gets changed to some random values.
Due to which i have to repeat the same task for arranging subviews many times.

I have created nib file without Auto Layout.

Can somebody tell me what wrong i am doing or what should i do to fix the subview permanently in the Xib.

Thanks in Advance. Looking for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following workaround. Adding an explicit `tableViewCellContentView` frame in a xib file fixes the problem. To do this open the xib as Source Code and add the following line in the `tableViewCellContentView` section:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="39"/>
```

`width` should be equal to `tableViewCell` `width` and `height` should be equal to `tableViewCell` `height` - 1

Such line is present in old xibs. It seems like Apple decided to optimise xibs but added new bug.